# Como recupero variables de un codigo qr

Tags: android-studio, variables-globales, qrcode

Buenas, tengo un codigo QR en mi aplicacion android, hasta los momentos me esta funcionando como deberia, la pregunta es que requiero que una vez que lea el codigo que le esta siendo pasado pueda manejar las variables, hasta ahora no tengo idea de como hacerlo, pues solo tengo un string completo, pero me gustaria saber como puedo recuperar variables pasadas por el string, les coloco el codigo del que hace el scan y del que recibe los datos:

**pre-scan activity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pre_scan);

    scanbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnscan);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
    }
    scanbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PreScan.this, LeerQR.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(data != null){
            final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
            result.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    result.setText(barcode.displayValue);
                    scanbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Scan Activity:**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leer_qr);
        cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        cameraView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        holder = cameraView.getHolder();
        barcode = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                .build();
        if(!barcode.isOperational()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, Couldn't setup the detector", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.finish();
        }
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcode)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedFps(24)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1920,1024)
                .build();
        cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try{
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LeerQR.this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }



            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();

            }
        });
        barcode.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes =  detections.getDetectedItems();
                if(barcodes.size() > 0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("barcode", barcodes.valueAt(0));
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

El caso es que no logro saber como procesar las variables que lee del scanner, por lo general seria una variable numerica y un correo, pero ni idea de como lo leeria.

Actualizo:

Identifique en que parte del codigo me trae la variable, me la trae completa como una cadena de texto, es aqui:

 `@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){`

```
        if(data != null){
```

//Aqui se me pasa una sola cadena de texto, es la que deseo separar en varias 
//variables para poder usarla en mi aplicacion
                final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
                result.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
//Este TextView no lo necesito, pero no se como convertir esto a una cadena 
//mas que hacerlo de la forma como aparece aqui
                        result.setText(barcode.displayValue);
                        String resultado = result.getText().toString();
//El toast era para probar si podia convertir el resultado en cadena, y si se puede, pero debo mostrar el TextView que no se deberia mostrar
Toast.makeText(PreScan.this, resultado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //scanbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

Me facilitaron la idea del string split, pero ni idea de como aplicarla

Comment: Ok, aclaro, si entiendo donde recupero la variable, seria aqui:
<code>
 final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");</code>
Lo que no se es como trabajar con las variables que recupero, es decir, necesito trabajar con tres variables que me va a pasar el qr, como hago para que una sola cadena de texto yo poder sacar lo que son las variables que debo usar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu pregunta no indicas el formato de la cadena que recuperas del QR. Para los casos donde necesitas separar una cadena en múltiples cadenas es necesario que la cadena original tenga algún carácter que se use como delimitador y usar el método Split().

```
// Suponiendo que barcode tienen un formato tipo: "var1;var2;var3"
String[] variables = barcode.split(":"); // split() debe regresar un arreglo de cadenas con 3 elementos

// Inspeccionando los elementos del array utilizando el índice.
variables[0]; // esto contendrá "var1"
variables[2]; // esto contendrá "var3"

// Tambien puedes usar un loop for para inspeccionar el arreglo
for (String var : variables)
{
   // aqui puedes usar var directamente
}
```

Puedes ahondar más en la siguiente liga:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string

Comment: Como usaria la variable directamente? se la puedo asignar a una constante?, como seria eso

Comment: Esta bien esto?
<code>
for (String var : variables)
                        {
                         Constantes.COMERCIO_CORREO = variables[0];
                         String montott = variables[1];     
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(PreScan.this, Constantes.COMERCIO_CORREO , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();</code>

Comment: Ya encontre el error, quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que el resultado poder convertirlo a string para poder hacer el split de las variables:

String resultado.toString(barcode.displayValue);